# Motorcycle: Irregular brake bite (front single disk)

Tags: motorcycle, brakes, brake-rotor

My motorcycle's front brake is giving a irregular bite.

I don't know how to express it in words please check the illustration below.

```
--------$^^^^^^^^-^-^-^-^-^^--^^^---^^^^^^----^^^|
~60Kmph          30kmph         20         10  0kmph 

- : No brake/bite
$ : applied front brake
^ : bite
```

The front feels as if it is jumping up and down when the brake is applied.

No problem with rear brake. This started after a ride in heavy rain.

Is it an alignment problem of the disk or wheel?

or something like disk bend?

Comment: The way I read your illustration, it seems to be correlated with the rotation speed of the wheel. I would a) inspect the tire for bulges (improbable), b) make sure the front wheel is balanced, and c) suspect the rotor to be warped.

Comment: **Replaced pad**, the problem exists..;
**Replaced Rotor**, The rotor wheel wont rotate as like the brake is applied.., disk gets hot, burnt my mechanic's hand...
**Break bleeded**, Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a warped brake rotor and/or brake pads. A warped rotor will grab the pads intermittently in the way you're trying to describe. In all likelihood replacing your brake rotor and brake pads will fix the issue. Be sure to replace both components, one or the other doesn't usually get you anywhere: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Should_you_replace_rotors_at_the_same_time_as_the_brake_pads

Comment: I think theres a definite difference between US and europe on this - in europe we mostly dont resurface rotors and routinely change pads without replacing rotors, a rotor normally lasts between two and three pad replacements.